# categorical features (object/float) selection for regression problem using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data, feature-selection

I have a set of **alphanumeric categorical features** `(c_1,c_2, ..., c_n)` and one **numeric target variable** `(prediction)` as a pandas dataframe. Can you please suggest to me any **feature selection algorithm** that I can use for this data set?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are solving a supervised learning problem like Regression or Classification.

First of all I suggest to transform the categorical features into numeric ones using one-hot encoding. Pandas provides an useful function that already does it:

```
dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=['feature-1', 'feature-2', ...])
```

If you have a limited number of features and a model that is not too computationally expensive you can test the combination of all the possible features, it is the best way however it is seldom a viable option.

A possible alternative is to sort all the features using the correlation with the target, then sequentially add them to the model, measure the goodness of my model and select the set of features that provides the best performance.
If you have high dimensional data, you can consider to reduce the dimensionality using PCA or another dimensionality reduction technique, it projects the data into a lower dimensional space reducing the number of features, obviously you will loose some information due to the PCA approximation.

These are only some examples of methods to perform feature selection, there are many others.

Final tips:

- Remember to split the data into Training, Validation and Test set.
- Often data normalization is recommended to obtain better results.
- Some models have embedded mechanism to perform feature selection (Lasso, Decision Trees, ...).